# How to append values into multidimensional numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I want to be able to append values and access said values in a multidimensional numpy array.

For example:

```
import numpy as np

animal = np.array([[]])

mammal = ["monkey","dog","cat"]
amphibian = ["frog","toad","salamanders"]
aquatic = ["fish","eel","whale"]

list = [mammal, amphibian, aquatic]

for i in list
   animal = np.append(animal, list[i])

animal = np.append(animal,bird[])
bird = np.append(bird,"eagle")

print(animal)
print(animal[2][2])
```

Expected output:

```
(["monkey","dog","cat"],
["frog","toad","salamanders"],
["fish","eel","whale"],
["eagle"])

"whale"
```

Comment: You should consider using a list of lists instead of a numpy array as your rows are not all the same size.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
import numpy as np

animal = np.empty((0, 3), str)

mammal = ["monkey","dog","cat"]
amphibian = ["frog","toad","salamanders"]
aquatic = ["fish","eel","whale"]

x = [mammal, amphibian, aquatic]

for i in x:
    animal = np.append(animal, np.array([i]), axis=0)

print(animal)
```

Output:

```
array([['monkey', 'dog', 'cat'],
       ['frog', 'toad', 'salamanders'],
       ['fish', 'eel', 'whale']], dtype='<U11')
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, defining `list` might cause a ton of problems, as it is a python builtin name.

Secondly, in the line:
`animal = np.append(animal, list[i])`,
`i` is one of the elements of `list`, it shouldn't be used as an index.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to numpy, you already have what you need it seems.

You can just append the list to the list of lists.

```
mammal = ["monkey","dog","cat"]
amphibian = ["frog","toad","salamanders"]
aquatic = ["fish","eel","whale"]

animal_list = [mammal, amphibian, aquatic]

animal_list.append(['eagle'])

print(animal_list)

print(animal_list[2][2])
```

prints

```
[['monkey', 'dog', 'cat'], ['frog', 'toad', 'salamanders'], ['fish', 'eel', 'whale'], ['eagle']]
whale
```

However, you can take the results and just covert it to a numpy array

```
np_animal_list = np.array(animal_list)
```

Comment: Skip the `list_of_lists` creation.  `animal_list.append(['eagle'])` should do.